# Davical/LDAP authentication - database error when creating new users

Tags: calendar, ldap, webdav

I have Davical 1.1.1 installed and working fine with the default authentication. I'm trying to enable LDAP authentication with an OpenLDAP 2.3 server. Authentication seems to be working fine (logs show that I'm getting the correct name & email address from the LDAP server), but I'm getting a database error when Davical attempts to create a new user. The same thing happens whether I try to log in to the web panel using LDAP credentials or log in as admin and use the Tools page to sync LDAP users.

Here's a log from an LDAP login attempt:

```
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:30 America/New_York] davical: LOG: Principal: Query: QF: SQL error "42846" - ERROR: cannot cast type text to bit"
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:30 America/New_York] davical: LOG: Principal: Query: QF: INSERT INTO dav_principal (username,email,user_active,modified,fullname,type_id,default_privileges) VALUES(:username,:email,:user_active,:modified,:fullname,:type_id,cast(:default_privileges as text)::BIT(24))
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:30 America/New_York] davical: LOG: Principal: Query: QF:     ":username" => "jon_williams"
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:30 America/New_York] davical: LOG: Principal: Query: QF:     ":email" => "jon@myserver.com"
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:30 America/New_York] davical: LOG: Principal: Query: QF:     ":user_active" => "1"
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:30 America/New_York] davical: LOG: Principal: Query: QF:     ":modified" => "2013-03-22 17:12:37"
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:30 America/New_York] davical: LOG: Principal: Query: QF:     ":fullname" => "Jon"
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:30 America/New_York] davical: LOG: Principal: Query: QF:     ":type_id" => "1"
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:30 America/New_York] davical: LOG: Principal: Query: QF:     ":default_privileges" => "000000000001111000000000"
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:30 America/New_York] davical: LOG: index.php: Query: QF: SQL error "42804" - ERROR: column "user_no" is of type integer but expression is of type boolean HINT: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression."
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:30 America/New_York] davical: LOG: index.php: Query: QF: INSERT INTO collection (user_no, parent_container, dav_name, dav_etag, dav_displayname, is_calendar, is_addressbook, default_privileges, created, modified, resourcetypes) VALUES( :user_no, :parent_container, :collection_path, :dav_etag, :di
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:30 America/New_York] davical: LOG: index.php: Query: QF: splayname, :is_calendar, :is_addressbook, :privileges::BIT(24), current_timestamp, current_timestamp, :resourcetypes );
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:30 America/New_York] davical: LOG: index.php: Query: QF:     ":user_no" => ""
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:30 America/New_York] davical: LOG: index.php: Query: QF:     ":parent_container" => "/jon_williams/"
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:30 America/New_York] davical: LOG: index.php: Query: QF:     ":dav_etag" => "-1"
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:30 America/New_York] davical: LOG: index.php: Query: QF:     ":collection_path" => "/jon_williams/calendar/"
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:30 America/New_York] davical: LOG: index.php: Query: QF:     ":displayname" => " calendar"
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:30 America/New_York] davical: LOG: index.php: Query: QF:     ":resourcetypes" => "<DAV::collection/><urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav:calendar/>"
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:30 America/New_York] davical: LOG: index.php: Query: QF:     ":is_calendar" => "1"
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:30 America/New_York] davical: LOG: index.php: Query: QF:     ":is_addressbook" => ""
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:30 America/New_York] davical: LOG: index.php: Query: QF:     ":privileges" => ""
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:31 America/New_York] davical: ***: ERROR:AwlDBDialect: Named parameter '0' does not begin with a colon.
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:31 America/New_York] davical: ***: ERROR:AwlDBDialect: Named parameter '1' does not begin with a colon.
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:31 America/New_York] davical: LOG: Session: Query: QF: SQL error "08P01" - ERROR: bind message supplies 0 parameters, but prepared statement "pdo_pgsql_stmt_090efd34" requires 2"
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:31 America/New_York] davical: LOG: Session: Query: QF: UPDATE usr SET last_used = (SELECT session_start FROM session WHERE session.user_no = ? ORDER BY session_id DESC LIMIT 1) WHERE user_no = ?;
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:31 America/New_York] davical: LOG: Session: Query: QF:     "0" => ""
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:31 America/New_York] davical: LOG: Session: Query: QF:     "1" => ""
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:31 America/New_York] davical: LOG: Login: Query: QF: SQL error "42804" - ERROR: column "user_no" is of type integer but expression is of type boolean HINT: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression."
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:31 America/New_York] davical: LOG: Login: Query: QF: INSERT INTO session (session_id, user_no, session_key) VALUES( ?, ?, ? )
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:31 America/New_York] davical: LOG: Login: Query: QF:     "0" => "41"
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:31 America/New_York] davical: LOG: Login: Query: QF:     "1" => ""
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:31 America/New_York] davical: LOG: Login: Query: QF:     "2" => "d0f33746419fc250d60890666ee5a1fb"
[25-Mar-2013 15:53:31 America/New_York] davical: Login failure: ERR: Could not create new session.
```

There seem to be two errors here - one when attempting to create the principal for the user, and another when attempting to create the default collection set. In the latter case, it seems that the principal is not returning a value for "user_no" to use for the new collection.

The Davical LDAP documentation (http://wiki.davical.org/w/Configuration/LDAP) indicates that the mapping field for 'user_no' should correspond to a Unix uid in LDAP, but our LDAP server doesn't use uid numbers, so I removed this mapping from the config file. Here is what the configuration currently looks like (with domain names changed to protect the innocent):

```
<?php
  $c->domain_name = "calendar.myserver.com";
  $c->admin_email = 'webmaster@myserver.com';
  $c->pg_connect[] = 'dbname=davical port=5432 user=davical_app';

  $c->authenticate_hook['call'] = 'LDAP_check';
  $c->do_not_sync_from_ldap = array('admin' => true);
  $c->authenticate_hook['config'] = array(
    'host'          => 'ldaps://www.myserver.com:636', //host name of your LDAP Server
    'bindDN'        => 'cn=Manager,dc=myserver,dc=com', //DN to bind request to this server (if required)
    'passDN'        => 'nice_try', //Password of request bind
    'baseDNUsers'   => 'ou=people,dc=myserver,dc=com', //where to look for valid user
    'filterUsers' => 'objectClass=inetOrgPerson', //filter which must validate a user according to RFC4515, i.e. surrounded by brackets
    'protocolVersion' => 3, // important for simple auth (no sasl)
    'mapping_field' => array(
                             'username' => 'uid',
                             'modified'  => 'modifyTimestamp',
                             'fullname' => 'cn', // "Common Name"
                             'email'    => 'mail'), //used to create the user based on his LDAP properties
    'format_updated'=> array('Y' => array(0,4),
                             'm' => array(4,2),
                             'd' => array(6,2),
                             'H' => array(8,2),
                             'M' => array(10,2),
                             'S' => array(12,2)), // map LDAP "modifyTimestamp" field to SQL "updated" field
     'scope' => 'subtree' // Search scope to use, defaults to subtree ( applies to BOTH user and group mappings )
                           // Allowed values: base, onelevel, subtree.
  );
  include('drivers_ldap.php');
```

Is this a bug in Davical 1.1.1, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: [DAViCal Configuration/LDAP documentation](http://davical.dhits.nl/index.php?title=Configuration/LDAP) says that removing `user_no` field mapping (by commenting/removing `user_no'  => 'uidNumber'` line is to tell DAViCAL no to match local user by with Unix uid from LDAP.

Either you want you local DAViCal users to have the same ID that the one from the LDAP or not: it's up to you.